# How can I determine if I'm using a Sitecore development licence

Tags: sitecore

I'm new to Sitecore and I'm need to check what sort of licence is currently in use.

I would have though the licence type would be mentioned in the licence xml file, or available through to the admin user interface..but apparently not.

What ideas on where this information is held, or how I can determine the licence type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top right of the Sitecore Login will show you who it is licensed to.

Another sign is the development license turns some parts of the Sitecore Login screen yellow

/sitecore/login

Answer (score 1):

There are differences in licence.xml file for partner and for client, for example **purpose** element in licence.xlm file for partner starts with text: "The Sitecore partner {partnername} (“the Licensee”) is licensed" and for client starts with text: "The customer {customername} (“the Licensee”) is licensed".

Partner licence is used for development, and client licence should be used on production.
Client licence contains information about number of allowed installations.